# based on the browser size i want to execute the logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

var w = window.innerWidth;

```html
<script>


var w = window.innerWidth; //// we will get the width of the browser




</script>

<div>

for()   // for1
my logic
</div>

<div>

for()

my logic


</div>

if the browser size is maximum i want to execute for loop 1.
if the browser size in minimum i want to execute the for loop 2

 i tried many ways cant able to fix,


1)wrote a funtion in the script and tried to call the funtion in body tag using onload.
and many ways.
```

//// we will get the width of the browser




for()   // forloop1
my logic




for()  //forloop2
my logic

if the browser size is maximum i want to execute for loop 1.
if the browser size in minimum i want to execute the for loop 2

i tried many ways cant able to fix,

1)wrote a funtion in the script and tried to call the funtion in body tag using onload.

Comment: I have no idea what your exact problem is. `if ( w > 640 ) { for(); } else { for2(); }`

Comment: hi shilly, i have 2 for loops in my code, if the browser size is maximum i want to execute the first loop if not second

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clearly explain. But if I well understood, you want, depending on the width of the screen execute one of two "for"?

Here you go :

```
var w = window.innerWidth; //you get the width of the windwow
if(w < 500){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        //do what you want when the width is < than 500
    }
else{
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        //do what you want when the width is > than 500
    }
}
```